# EJB Project can't be hot deploy? MyEclipse10 & JBoss4.0.5GA

Tags: java, jboss, ejb-3.0

When I deploy an EJB3 project in the JBoss server.
There is no log in the Console.
I can't find the JNDI name. This is wrong.
[image: 001]
[image: 002]

And when I try to run an EJB Client to remote call the EJB, I get an Exception:
[image: 003]

How can I solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: JBoss 4.0.5 ??? You know that is a decade old, right? I wonder if it even supports the EJB 3.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use EJB 3 (e.g. with `@Stateless`), but JBoss 4 is too old to support this. Try a more up-to-date version, e.g. JBoss AS 7.

Comment: I have change the JBoss4 to JBoss7.1.1.

It works... and I can hot deploy an EJB project now.

Thank you!